# Is Moq mocking a subinterface return value and ignoring the intermediary step a bug or a feature?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, configuration, moq

I was recently building an app and a coworker wrote a setup I swore would fail. I was wrong. In it a factory method was set up with an expected value of true and would return an integer. Because we didn't mock our configuration, the bool would always be false.

The setup was:

```
 var homeStoreDataServiceFactory = new Mock<IHomeStoreDataServiceFactory>();
 homeStoreDataServiceFactory.Setup(service => service.Create(true).GetStoreNumber())
                .Returns(5);
```

I thought that a call to `factory.Create(false)` would not generate *the* mock object, and thus we would get 0 for the integer instead of the mocked value 5. Instead, no matter what we changed the service.Create(X) to, calls to GetStoreNumber **always return 5 as if we'd used It.IsAny()**.

I've built up an MVCE so that you can see what I'm confused about:

```
using System;
using Moq;

namespace MoqBugMCV
{
    public interface IItemServiceFactory
    {
        IItemService Create(bool shouldCreateServiceA);
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IItemService
    {
        Item GetItem();
    }

    public class ItemManager
    {
        private readonly IItemService _itemService;

        public ItemManager(IItemServiceFactory itemServiceFactory)
        {
            _itemService = itemServiceFactory.Create(true); //<==== configured true (like by app.config at runtime or something)
        }

        public Item GetAnItem()
        {
            return _itemService.GetItem();
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {

        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var itemServiceFactory = new Mock<IItemServiceFactory>();
            var chrisItem = new Item {Name = "Chris's Amazing Item", Price = 1000000};
            itemServiceFactory.Setup(factory => factory.Create(true).GetItem())
                .Returns(chrisItem);

            var itemManager = new ItemManager(itemServiceFactory.Object);

            var theItem = itemManager.GetAnItem();

            Console.WriteLine("The item is {0} and costs {1}", theItem.Name, theItem.Price);

            var itemServiceFactoryBroken = new Mock<IItemServiceFactory>();
            itemServiceFactoryBroken.Setup(factory => factory.Create(false).GetItem()).Returns(chrisItem); //expecting this to fail, because IItemServiceFactory.Create(true) is configured

            itemManager = new ItemManager(itemServiceFactoryBroken.Object);
            theItem = itemManager.GetAnItem();

            Console.WriteLine("The item is {0} and costs {1}", theItem.Name, theItem.Price); //would expect the item would be null or values to be blank
        }
    }
}
```

So... is this a bug or feature, or am I not understanding something about Moq?

Comment: Do you get the same result with `....Returns(() => 5);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it seems that any filters applied to intermediate dereferences on recursive Moqs are ignored as [per here](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/142) - even with an `It.Is<>` matcher, the filter is ignored. i.e. at present, recursive mocks will always generate the equivalent of `It.IsAny<>` on any parameters on the intermediate dereferences, as you noted.

For now, I would break up:

```
.Setup(service => service.Create(true).GetStoreNumber()
```

and split this into:

```
mockFactory.Setup(f => f.Create(xx))
mockService.Setup(service => service.GetStoreNumber())
```

Applying this separation to your `MVCE` example, the below setup only mocks the `factory.Create(false)`, leaving `factory.Create(true)` to its default return value of `null` for reference types:

```
var itemServiceFactory = new Mock<IItemServiceFactory>();
var itemService = new Mock<IItemService>();

itemService.Setup(svc => svc.GetItem()).Returns(chrisItem);
itemServiceFactory.Setup(factory => factory.Create(false))
    .Returns(itemService.Object);

var itemManager = new ItemManager(itemServiceFactory.Object);
var theItem = itemManager.GetAnItem(); // Get NRE on _itemService.GetItem as expected
```

And accordingly, mocking `factory.Create(true)` will use the setup service, and `GetAnItem()` will return the amazing item.

**Edit**

It seems there is a way to achieve a filter on the intermediate step and to compress the setups of both factory and service mocks in one go, using [Linq to Mocks](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#linq-to-mocks):

```
var itemServiceFactory = Mock.Of<IItemServiceFactory>(
    fac => fac.Create(false) == Mock.Of<IItemService>(
        svc => svc.GetItem() == chrisItem));

var itemManager = new ItemManager(itemServiceFactory);
var theItem = itemManager.GetAnItem();
```

Comment: I understand what is happening here, I'm trying to determine if this is a bug or a feature of Moq. My coworker wrote a test using the original code block (the "recursive mock" in your link out to Moq issues) and I thought it would fail because the dataservice output by the factory would have been null because the test was configuring the site using a `false` value. Unfortunately (and embarrassingly) it passed. Considering it's not categorized in their open issues, I would assume no one is sure yet? Or is this intended behavior?

Comment: This certainly isn't intuitive behaviour, and thanks for picking this up - I wasn't aware of the limitation. To be honest, I've never tried to use recursive Mocks other than for their default behaviour, and typically only on Properties. Linq To Mocks seems a reasonable workaround for compactness. I've generally erred on the side of verbosity and usually explicitly setup all levels of  dependencies, FWIW.

Comment: I repro'd this issue in the moq issues on github, as the linked issue illustrates the bug but doesn't identify what's really happening. https://github.com/Moq/moq4/issues/147

Answer (score 1):

After wrestling a bit with a few other things, I returned to this to investigate further.

If you change the second example to:

```
        var itemServiceFactoryBroken = new Mock<IItemServiceFactory>(MockBehavior.Strict); //Strict behavior is important!!
        itemServiceFactoryBroken.Setup(factory => factory.Create(false).GetItem()).Returns(chrisItem); //expecting this to fail, because IItemServiceFactory.Create(true) is configured

        itemManager = new ItemManager(itemServiceFactoryBroken.Object);
        theItem = itemManager.GetAnItem();

        Console.WriteLine("The item is {0} and costs {1}", theItem.Name, theItem.Price);
```

It will throw an exception because the setup was not configured. I still believe this is a bug, its definitely not what you would expect to happen. The GetItem should not be returning a chrisItem, as the factory is not set up to be outputting a mocked class that returns anything given the configuration of the system under test.

However strict behavior mocks appear to be "aware" that this setup is invalid and will throw an exception. There seems to be a gulf in the pattern of behavior in these instances.